# Make PIXI JS do scaling from dynamically set height and width

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am trying to do a full screen zoom in animation on a picture. Initially, I am dynamically setting the height and width of the image to match the screen height and width (ratio maintained). But once I start the scaling animation, it starts scaling it down from the actual image dimensions, not the one's I set  dynamically. How can I do a scaling animation on a image from say `1.5` to `1` where `1` means my dynamically set values for the width and height of the image,

I have reproduced the problem here, for 2.5 seconds the image will cover full height and width but once the animation starts, it will shrink to its actual size.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let image;
  let scale = 1.5;
  let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer($(window).width(), $(window).height(), {
    transparent: true,
    resolution: 1
  });
  document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.view);

  /* create stage */
  let stage = new PIXI.Container();

  PIXI.loader.add('my-image',"https://i.imgur.com/JaBEvbC.png").load(setup);

  function setup() {
    
    image = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('my-image');
    image.x = renderer.width / 2;
    image.y = renderer.height / 2;
    image.anchor.set(0.5);
    
    image.height = $(window).height();
    image.width = $(window).width();
    
    stage.addChild(image);
    renderer.render(stage);

   setTimeout(() => animationLoop(), 2500) 
  }

  function animationLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
    scale -= 0.005;
    scale = scale < 1 ? 1.5 : scale;
    image.scale.set(scale);
    renderer.render(stage);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.3/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div align="center" id="display">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of scaling the image, I recommend to interpolate the width and height of the image dynamically, from the original size to the final size.

Store the original size of the window to some properties, instead of changing the `.width` and `.height` in `setup()`:

```js
image.orig_w = image.width;
image.orig_h = image.height;
```

Calculate a interpolation value in the range [0.0, 1.0] in the `animationLoop`, dependent on `scale`:

```js
scale -= 0.005;
scale = scale < 1 ? 1.5 : scale;

var a = 2.0*(1.5-scale); // from [1.5, 1.0] to [0.0, 1.0]
```

Calculate the size of the image dependent on the value `a`:

```js
image.width  = image.orig_w + ($(window).width() - image.orig_w) * a; 
image.height = image.orig_h + ($(window).height() - image.orig_h) * a;
```

See the example, where I applied the suggested changes to your original code:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  let image;
  let scale = 1.5;
  let renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer($(window).width(), $(window).height(), {
    transparent: true,
    resolution: 1
  });
  document.getElementById('display').appendChild(renderer.view);

  /* create stage */
  let stage = new PIXI.Container();

  PIXI.loader.add('my-image',"https://i.imgur.com/JaBEvbC.png").load(setup);

  function setup() {
    
    image = PIXI.Sprite.fromImage('my-image');
    image.x = renderer.width / 2;
    image.y = renderer.height / 2;
    image.anchor.set(0.5);
    
    image.orig_w = image.width;
    image.orig_h = image.height;
    
    stage.addChild(image);
    renderer.render(stage);

   setTimeout(() => animationLoop(), 2500) 
  }

  function animationLoop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
    scale -= 0.005;
    scale = scale < 1 ? 1.5 : scale;

    var a = 2.0*(1.5-scale); // from [1.5, 1.0] to [0.0, 1.0]
    image.width  = image.orig_w + ($(window).width() - image.orig_w) * a; 
    image.height = image.orig_h + ($(window).height() - image.orig_h) * a; 

    renderer.render(stage);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/4.8.3/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align="center" id="display"></div>
```